# Toad SQL Issue for Timestamp without Seconds

Tags: oracle, date, toad

I am executing the following sql in Toad. Oracle is RDBMS
  I only need Date in yyyymmdd HH24:mi, but I get Date only as shown below

```
  alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI';  

  SELECT to_date('22/07/1980 00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') dt FROM dual    

  22/07/1980
```

Required Output

```
  22/07/1980 00:00
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I think converting to a string type is the way forward here...

Comment: Apparently TOAD doesn't honor the NLS_DATE_FORMAT. You probably need to find some configuration in TOAD that controls the _display_ of dates.

Comment: Oracle is the RDBMS, I  wanted the result in to_date as shown above and not char please

Comment: `to_date()` creates a `DATE` value. A `DATE` has no format at all. Any format that you _see_ is applied by the application _displaying_ the value. If you want to ensure a specific output format you need to use `to_char()` or configure your SQL client to use that.

Comment: Did you try running both statements as a script?

Comment: Thanks Boniest, I am creating a table, so even though we run this as a script, still the table is created without time stamo and this happens only for 00:00 and not for others for example - 00:01 or 00:02 etc

Comment: If you're viewing the table data in the datagrid, then Toad automatically removes the time part if it's midnight. That's deliberate - if all values in the column are at midnight, it's extra info that is useless. If you run the select as a script (including the alter session), then it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used sql plus and spooled the file instead of Toad, used NLS Date format conversion here, but as this is command based, wanted to use GUI based TOAD.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `to_char()` -- you want to return the date as a string, not a date.  As far as I know, the date is returned without the time, and I don't think the NLS changes that.

So:

```
SELECT to_char(to_date('22/07/1980 00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'
                      ),  'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'
              ) as dt
FROM dual
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, Is there no way that a to_date conversion will return date with hours and minutes, are we forced to change it to to_char

Comment: I have used sql plus and spooled the file instead of Toad, used NLS here, thanks for all your assistance, seems like Toad cannot be relied upon Date format conversions

Comment: @las . . . Oracle stores a time component with all dates.  It is part of the `date` data type.